# How can I plot 4D results as a surface in R?

Tags: r, plot, plotly, raster, rayshader

I have a model including a three-way interaction term (X*Y*Z). I have used this model to create predictions across the parameter space. Thus, I have four pieces of information to convey: X, Y, Z, and Probability. If I had a simple interaction, I would plot a heatmap with X~Y and color would be Probability, but now I need that as a 3D plot.

```
example_results <- expand.grid(x = 1:8,
                  y = seq(from = -1.85, to = 3.58, length.out = 15),
                  z = seq(from = 0, to = 2.41, length.out = 15)) %>% 
  mutate(probability = sample(seq(from = 0, to = 1, length.out = 3000), 1800))
```

`plot_ly` seems to understand its own relationships within data, whereas I want just to plot my results. `rayshader` seemed perfect, but is apparently unable to decouple height (z) from fill (probability). `rasterVis` objects to cuts.

I will greatly appreciate any advice on how to plot all the information in one image in R.

Thanks!

[image: rayshader outcome]

[image: cubic outcome]

Comment: One way to do this would be to plot contours of the `probability` variable as a function of x, y, and z.  The `misc3d` package can do that.  If `probability` doesn't vary smoothly, that won't look good; then maybe just plot points or spheres on a grid of x, y, z values, with colour or size depending on the probability.  `rgl` can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `rayshader` and `ggplot2`. One problem is that the example data you have posted uses `expand.grid()`. Each value of `x` and `y` has every value of `z`, so you won't see a difference in heights with this data. I'll just select random rows for each value of `x` and `y` for demonstration purposes:

```r
library(dplyr)
dat <- example_results |>
    group_by(x, y) |>
    filter(row_number() == sample(row_number(), 1))
```

Once you've done this you can use `ggplot2` to create two separate 2d heatmaps, one for the height and one for the fill. Make sure to set `color` in both to the height value (`z` in this case):

```r
library(ggplot2)
heatmap_fill <- ggplot(dat) +
    geom_tile(aes(x, y, fill = probability, color = z)) +
    theme_void() +
    theme(legend.position = "none")

heatmap_height <- ggplot(dat) +
    geom_tile(aes(x, y, fill = z, color = z)) +
    theme_void() +
    theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Then you can just use `rayshader` to render these, providing the fill heatmap as the `ggobj` and the height heatmap as `ggobj_height`. I've turned off shadows in this case so it renders quickly:

```r
library(rayshader)
plot_gg(
    ggobj = heatmap_fill,
    ggobj_height = heatmap_height,
    multicore = TRUE, width = 5, height = 5,
    shadow = FALSE,
    raytrace = FALSE,
    scale = 500, windowsize = c(1280, 720), zoom = 0.85,
    phi = 90, theta = 0
)
```

Output:

[image]

The quality is *much* better than this - I had to make it very small and reduce the colours to 64 get it under the 2mb image upload limit. See [here](https://ibb.co/cFBC4wM) for the higher quality version.